# I have an equation I would like solving.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

I need to solve the following problem

> Decorator A is painting a large wall. At her current rate, she will
>   complete the wall in 1 hour and 40 minutes.
>
> Decorator B is painting a similar wall, although he is a little faster
>   and will likely complete the wall in 1 hour.
>
> Decorator C is painting a similar wall too, but he is slower and will
>   complete the wall in 2 hours.
>
> Assuming Decorators A, B and C and 6 more decorators, three of which
>   are as fast as B and 3 of which are as fast as C collaborated on the
>   same wall, how long would they complete a wall together?

However, I don't know how to set up a proper model for this question. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What have you worked out so far?

Comment: Not much! I am struggling to work out how to start this one.

Comment: You could add the mathematical modeling tag if you want. And add that you need help in translating this written problem into a good mathematical model that makes sense.

Comment: That would be good. I think this website might be a little too specialist for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What percentage of a wall would they paint together in an hour?

Each A-class painter would paint $\frac{3}{5}$ of a wall, since he would need $\frac{5}{3}$ hour (or 1h40) for a full wall.

Each B-class painter would paint a full wall.

Each C-class would paint $\frac12$ of a wall.

So, all the nine painters would paint, in an hour:

$\frac35+4\times1+4\times\frac12=\frac{33}{5}$ of a wall.

Now, how much time to finish a wall?

Comment: I'm getting 6m 27secs.

Comment: $\frac{33}{5}$ wall in $1$ hour => $1$ wall in ... hour? It takes less to finish to full wall. How much less?  Well because there is a direct proportional relationship between the two, we can just divide both sides by the same number. We choose to divide by $\frac{33}{5}$ the left an the right side. This gives us for the left side $\frac{33}{5} \text{ wall } / \frac{33}{5} = 1 \text{ wall }$ and for the right side $1 \text{ hour } / \frac{33}{5} = 0.1515151515... \text{ hour}$.

Comment: So I'm wrong then?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, I get 9m 5s (not that seconds are much relevant, but it may help to check results).

Comment: I have just forgotten everything. I got grade C GCSE 15 years ago. (I'm an artist now, so not a lot of call for MAths).

Comment: @PeterMitchell This is the part of a wall the nine painters will paint in an hour. That is, almost 6 walls and a half per hour, thus a bit less that 10 minutes for a wall (since an hour equals $6\times10$ minutes), and more exactly 9m 5s

Comment: Thankyou for you help - I am sure you are correct. I am using this to calculate how much faster I can render computer images with my 8 new computers as well as my workstation (My WS renders an image in 1:40s, 4 computers render in 0:60s and 4 in 2:00s.

Comment: I just preferred the 'decorator' analogy.

Comment: Ok great, if this helped, you can accept the answer (press the check button), then Jean-Claude Arbaut gets more credit for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Think about: How much of a wall does each painter cover in a minute?

Comment: Wow. Ok. Let me have a go.